# Nest Camera No longer Triggering

Tags: nest-api, home-automation, home-assistant, nest-device-access

I have recently integrated my Nest cams with Home Assistant. A Nest Hello door bell and the Nest Cam in the Google Home Hub Max.

Everything worked great at first, I had the live stream coming through from both cams. I also had some automations setup with both cams.

The day after I had set it up I found both cameras had turned off. This was because I had the Home/Away setting on in the Nest app so when I was at home the cameras would turn off and when I was away they would turn on. I turned this setting off in the Nest app and turned both cameras back on.

After turning the cameras back on I had the live streams of both cameras coming through again to Home Assistant. I went to test if the automations still worked and the Nest Hello Door Bell automations did and do still work but the Google Home Max automations did not work anymore.

I had the Home Hub Max camera triggering automations when detecting a person but it seems like the detection is not getting sent through to Home Assistant? I have also tried this with Motion detection and even Sound but I don’t see anything being recorded in Home Assistant.

The Nest Hello Door Bell, however, is working great and I see the detections being recorded in Home Assistant and the automations being triggered.

The live stream from the Home Hub Max is still working great in Home Assistant which makes it a little strange that the Person and Motion Detection is not working.

I have tried re-integrating the devices by removing and re-adding Nest to Home Assistant but I still get the same results.
I am also still getting motion detected notifications in the actual Nest App from the Nest cam in the Home Hub Max.

I really would like to get the Home Hub Max triggering on detection again in Home Assistant.
Has anyone else had the same experience or solved this before? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the diy stack exchange or the iot stack exchange. Unfortunately your question is off-topic here, as it's not programming-related.

Answer (score 1):

I have been digging into this myself with the integration owner.
It appears that the Google Pub/Sub topic from the Nest SDM API is not showing any camera events (Motion/person detection). I have created a subscription to the Google Pub/Sub from the SDM API and I can see the events being fired off by the Nest Thermostat however there are no messages for any camera events from the Nest Hub Max. The device is setup properly as I receive notifications in the Nest app for events and I can also get the rtsp stream from the SDM Api. My guess is maybe something in the firmware is preventing the events from going to the Pub/Sub topic as they should for the Nest Hub Max.

Answer (score 0):

Many users reports of nest hub display not publishing events at all, independent of home assistant