# Google Nest CameraMotion, CameraPerson and CameraSound not worlking for newer devices

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, nest

**Please continue this discussion in this thread: [Nest Camera No longer Triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67895035/nest-camera-no-longer-triggering)**

I have an old Nest Doorbell, an Google Nest Hub Max, and a Google Nest Camera (2021) connected to the power, and I only get CameraMotion, CameraPerson, and CameraSound for the old Nest Doorbell.

Doing some debug at Cloud Console, I could find that there are no events being published for the Nest Hub Max and Google Nest Camera (2021), however, I get events for the Nest Doorbell and a Nest Thermostat. Given that I already re-authorized all the devices I can only deduct that the publisher just isn't working (a google side issue).

I hope someone from Google API team checking this StackOverflow that could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made a [devices.list](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/list) call?

Mentions here (https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize#make_a_device_list_call):

> This call is required as part of authorization. Until this call is made:
>
> - The authorized project will not appear on PCM.
> - Events will not be published.

Command to execute:

```sh
curl -X GET 'https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/**project-id**/devices' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer **access-token**'
```

Comment: ScottMcC, the device.list call was made. This is the same issue as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67895035/nest-camera-no-longer-triggering.